# Why have our site's links stopped working in IE today?

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer

The company website is DNN-based: http://www.mrisoftware.com. This morning I was alerted that links "don't work", but nothing has changed today, so I'm stumped.

I verified that this is the case in Internet Explorer, although Firefox and Chrome are fine. The behavior: when the link is clicked on, it focuses, but the target URL doesn't resolve. A right-click opens in a new tab. I've tried poking around for answers on Google but this doesn't seem to be a common enough problem to have obvious answers at the top, and I'm stumped.

Naturally, the site was developed by an outside contractor, so we don't have a Web person here I can just ask (apart from me...and I'm, as above, stumped.)

Comment: What version of IE does the problem happen in, is the problem with all links or just certain ones. Did the report come from inside or outside the company? I just tried the site in IE9 and everything worked ok.

Comment: All links; IE8; we've verified it internally but the original reports were from clients.

Comment: Yep, confirmed - all links in IE8 don't appear to do anything! There are a number of validation errors on the page... incorrectly nested elements etc. some of these errors could be causing this.

Answer (score 7):

I tested it locally, and it seems that these two lines are causing the problem:

```
<script src="http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>mktoMunchkin("155-CYD-020");</script>
```

They add the following line to every `<a href="">` tag:
_mchInsLnk="true"

This causes them to not function right.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you and @MarcVeens have said it looks like the marketing analytics firm your company uses ([Marketo](http://www.marketo.com/)) updated their link tracking script and broke IE8 in the process.

You can contact [their support here](http://www.marketo.com/contact/index.php), I imagine they are aware of the problem but there are no updates on their company blog.

As a temporary workaround you could use the following code which targets all versions of IE save for IE8 (the '!' in !IE8 is the NOT operator).

```
<!--[if !IE 8]>
   <script src="http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
   <script>mktoMunchkin("155-CYD-020");</script>
<![endif]-->
```